# Need help creating a Context-Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to generate a CFG for the following $L$, but I'm stuck on how to do this.

$$L = \{0^i1^j2^k\mid i<j+k\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know anything about context-free grammars, I'll feel free to give what might be a full solution to half the problem, or might be completely wrong. Remember that last bit: might very well be completely wrong. The good news is that I would venture to guess that even if it's wrong, it's probably not *completely* wrong.

Elements of $L$ look like this:
$$0^{p+q}1^j2^k=0^p(0^q1^j)2^k,$$
where either:

1. $p<k$ and $q \le j$, or
2. $p \le k$ and $q < j$.

**Option 1:**
\begin{array}{cl}
A \to A2 \mid B2 \mid 2& \text{We can have as many $2$s at the end as we like, but at least one.}\\
B \to 0B2 \mid C \mid 02& \text{We can add $0$s to the left as we add $2$s to the right.} \\
C \to 1 \mid 01 \mid 0C1 \mid C1 &\text{We can add as many $1$s as we like, and as many zeros as $1$s.}
\end{array}

Comment: I don't think `00222` works with this CFG.

Comment: To use what is probably all the wrong notation: $A\to B2 \to (0B2)2 = 0B22 \to 0(02)22 = 00222$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Try using productions

$$A\to A2\mid 0A2\mid 0B2$$

and

$$B\to B1\mid \ldots\;,$$

where I’ve left some alternatives (and some other productions) for you to figure out.

**Added:** The CFG with productions $S\to S1$, $A\to 0S1$, and $S\to 1$ generates the language $\{0^j1^k:j<k\}$; do you see why?

Comment: Well, I know that some of the strings that can be created from this language include `12`, `011`, `00222`, and `0001122`.

Comment: @Jose: Let’s start with something similar but a little easier. Can you design a CFG that generates the language $\{0^j1^k:j<k\}$?

Comment: I'm not sure about when we use $j$ and $k$, but if we do $0^n1^n$, then we can make a production $A -> 0A1$.

Comment: @Jose: You can use the same basic idea, but you also have to allow the non-terminal symbol to add a $1$ on the right **without** adding a $0$ on the left, and you have to make sure that at least one extra $1$ is generated at some point. I’ve added to my answer a CFG that does this; see if you can use the ideas embodied in it together with the original hint to come up with something.